# flutter textfield , every second time when click on it occurring "xxx was disposed with an active Ticker."

Tags: flutter

I dispose the controller in order ,i really don't know how this error happened.

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
_McCountingTextState#82606(tickers: tracking 1 ticker) was disposed with an active Ticker.

_McCountingTextState created a Ticker via its TickerProviderStateMixin, but at the time dispose() was called on the mixin, that Ticker was still active. All Tickers must be disposed before calling super.dispose().

Tickers used by AnimationControllers should be disposed by calling dispose() on the AnimationController itself. Otherwise, the ticker will leak.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:landlore/model/roomInfo.dart';

class RoomEditScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final RoomInfo roomInfo;
  RoomEditScreen({super.key, required this.roomInfo});

  @override
  State<RoomEditScreen> createState() => _RoomEditScreenState();
}

class _RoomEditScreenState extends State<RoomEditScreen> {
  RoomInfo? roomInfo;
  TextEditingController c1 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextField(
        controller: c1,
        onChanged: (value) {
          print(value);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    c1.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for any AnimationController instances in your widget. It might be in the same _RoomEditScreenState class or in another widget that is part of the same screen or navigation flow.

Ensure that you call dispose() on the AnimationController in the dispose() method of your State class. This should be done before calling super.dispose(). It should look something like this:

```
AnimationController _animationController;

@override
void dispose() {
  _animationController.dispose(); // Dispose the controller
  super.dispose();
}
```

Make sure that the AnimationController is initialized in the initState() method and is only used within the lifecycle of the state. If you don’t find the AnimationController in the _RoomEditScreenState, check other widgets that are part of the same screen or navigation flow.

Remember, every AnimationController should be disposed of to prevent memory leaks and other side effects like the one you’re encountering.

Comment: wow, it really not this class itself causing that error , but I had check every previous class, it is desperate.i give up

Comment: and I am not giving this up. turn out it is a code that generated by gpt that does not initial the animationController at initState causing this problem